# Routing issue on MVC5 identity Register form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 with Identity v2. My problem is that the URL being called back on a register failure has an issue as it is appending length=7 which generally means a problem with the routes, that I haven't been able to work out.

My register form is at localhost:44300/en-US/Account/Register and if you submit a form that returns an invalid server side validation (as an example, if the username is taken), then the form redirects you to localhost:44300/en-US/Account/Register?Length=7

This happens in the Register method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // The following line seems to call the URL with ?length=7
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have the following route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Edit:
My form tag is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    LoadingElementId = "loader",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure "
}, new { @id = "localForm" }))
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, and it's not causing any issues, but I'd love to get to the bottom if it as something is obviously wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I fixed the problem, I was missing a value for route dictionary:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    LoadingElementId = "loader",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure "
}, new { @id = "localForm" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure the parameter only gets added **after** you do `return View(model)`? Because normally that *should* return you to the same url.

Chances are your form's action url is wrong, but due to your `RedirectToAction` it would ignore this.

If so, check your `BeginForm`'s parameters, and try setting `null` for `RouteValueDictionary routeValues`